# Cannot call method 'farbtastic' of undefined

Tags: javascript, callback, farbtastic

I'm trying to include the farbtastic colorpicker in a plugin. However, it looks like the id could not be called and I get the following error:

> Cannot call method 'farbtastic' of undefined

My code:

```
wp_register_script( 'gap_farbtastic', gap_url . 'admin/js/farbtastic.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('gap_farbtastic');

    <form>
    <input type="text" id="color" name="color" value="#123456" />
     </form>             
   <div id="colorpicker"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
         $('#colorpicker').farbtastic('#color');
       });
     </script>
```

The js file get included, however the method cannot be called. What's wrong?

Comment: i think wrong js path (add url for right answer)

Comment: Works in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bmUy2/

Comment: i update "shyam" demo here:  http://jsfiddle.net/bmUy2/1/

Comment: Thanks, not sure yet where the fault is, but it's not in the code above.

Comment: @shyam Whatever I try, it does not seem to work. What else could be the problem? I'm working btw in a wordpress plugin file.